# Word change in SO's left side menu

Tags: feature-request, left-navigation

It's not the first time I'm going through the struggle "How can I go to the questions now?" in Stack Overflow.

The menu says, differently than most other websites in the network, Stack Overflow instead of Questions.

[image: SO left side menu]

Even in this Meta we have "Questions" instead

[image: Meta SO left side menu]

Should we change that?

Comment: I’m pretty sure it used to be there and it was changed by request. If I can find the post, I will link it here.

Comment: Thank you @BSMP, I couldn't find...

Comment: It changed because you joined a team. Joining a team makes that UI significantly more confusing and difficult to use. I guess that is the price you pay to get to answer questions two places at once....

Comment: Oh I see, that's the default. Shouldn't we do anything about it? @CodyGray

Comment: @CodyGray that's what mine looks like and I'm not in a team

Comment: @CodyGray I don't think this has anything to do with using Teams. It's been like this for a while and I never used Teams. Perhaps it is related to Teams but affects all users?

Comment: @CodyGray maybe you assumed I'm speaking about the word "Public". That I know and there's another question trying to understand that. Here is about having "Stack Overflow" instead of "Questions".

Comment: It’s not because anyone joined a Team. It’s because Teams exists. As we’ve designed Teams one of the biggest concerns was making it easy to tell the difference between public SO and a private Team. So calling “Questions” “Stack Overflow” was to help with disambiguating. I don’t know if it should stay or not but that’s why it is this way. It’s “Questions” on MSO because it was only changed on SO and nowhere else on the network... there’s no Teams anywhere else.

Comment: Understood. Inside of a Team where now reads "Stack Overflow" we will see "Questions" and "Stack Overflow". Changing it would make us see "Questions" and "Questions" (consider consistency has more importance than intuition). Wonder why inside of a team there's no "Public" nearby "Stack Overflow" and "Private" near the questions menu, considering that concept appeared outside the teams already.

Comment: I'm not in Teams and I see the same as the first graphic. No "Questions"